# validation of input().split()

Tags: python, python-3.x, input, split

i have to use input().split() for  inputting 4 items simultaneously in a row
and i don't know how to valid those 4item separately (e.g: for the second item it must be only decimal and 10 character or for the forth it must be less than 20 charcter little alphabet). can somebody help me about this??? thanks

myself can do it with 4 seperate input() but don't know how to do it in one input()

`my code`

```
name = "0"
identical_num = "wrong"
enterence_year = "wrong"
field= "0"

#name
    
while name.isalpha() == False or len(name)==0 or len(name)>20:
    name= input("Enter the NAME - at least 1 to 20, only character").lower()
        
#identical_num   
    
while True:
    try:
        if len(identical_num)==10 and identical_num.isdecimal():
            break
        else:
            identical_num = input("Enter the IDENTICAL_NUM , must be 10 digit")
    except ValueError:
        print("Invalid input!")
              
#enterence_year 

while True:
   try:
       if enterence_year not in range(1300,1501):
           enterence_year = int(input("Enter the ENTERENCE_YEAR , between 1300 to 1500"))
       else:
           break
                
   except ValueError:
       print("Invalid input!")
            
#field
    
while field.isalpha() == False or len(field)==0 or len(field)>20:
    field= input("Enter the FIELD - at least 1 to 20, only character").lower()
```

Comment: Example: `a,b,c,d = "sell me 12 cows".split()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code looks fine, As commented by @jarmod :

You can do:

```
name, identical_num, enterence_year, field = input("Enter 4 values separated by a space").split()
```

to get 4 values from 1 `input()`.

carry on with your code.

Answer (score 2):

You can ask user input to be space-separated, split all the values by whitespace, and then individually validate each of the values. A common try-except can be used to catch all `ValueError`s

Sample code:

```py
def validate_name(name):
    if name.isalpha() == False or len(name) == 0 or len(name) > 20:
        raise ValueError("name is at least 1 to 20, only character")


while True:
    # strips extra whitespace on either side of the input
    name, identical_num, enterence_year, field = (
        input("Enter space-separated values: ").strip().split()
    )

    try:
        # validate each field
        validate_name(name)
        # etc ...
        break
    # catch exceptions together
    except ValueError as e:
        print(e)
```